# Скругление углов у дуги на Canvas в Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, рисование

У меня есть Canvas, на котором нарисована дуга с помощью drawArc
Дуга рисуется с заданной толщиной, но по краям у неё острые углы. Можно ли их как-то скруглить?

Comment: Нарисуйте окружности с диаметром толщины дуги и центрами в точках начала и конца дуги.

Comment: рисунок нужен..